# Installing ubuntu-no option to install with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, windows-10, usb-installation

This is the first time trying to install ubuntu for me.

Basically I followed along this tutorial in YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gYz5DoOkIE

I am not given the option to install Ubuntu alongside windows 10. However it does show up when I click on "something else". I don't know how to go from there though.

Here are some steps I've taken so far

- created a system image on external usb to backup windows
- Shrink the Windows 10 partition to make space for Ubuntu (shrunk 50000mb as in video)
- installed ubuntu 16.04.1 onto usb
- installed Universal USB Installer
- booted into Ubuntu Linux Installation environment and began installing Ubuntu (did not finish installation)

How do I install along side Windows 10, I imagine it's with using "something else". I had windows 7 previously installed on this computer, and both 7 and windows 10 show up in "something else".

Answer (score 0):

I found out why I was having trouble seeing "free space" in "something else."
Back when I looked in Windows Disk management, I saw that I had 5 partitions, which is for some reason (unsure the reason why) to have free space an option when in "something else."

One reason that I had so many partitions, is I bought my laptop with windows 7 pre-installed. Then I bought windows 8, and finally upgraded to windows 10 from there. Interestingly, there was no windows 8 partition, but separate partitions a windows 7 launcher and windows 10 launcher within the "something else". Also, which made things a challenge, my files were mainly stored in within the C: which had windows 7 launcher on it. And so I didn't delete C:, but had to delete other partitions that allowed for free space to install linux.